# Adding to beginning of string with regex

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to add two hashes to all strings that begin with a letter following a dot.

It should apply only if it is the beginning of the string. I'm new to regex, so I'm not sure how I should do the adding. Any help?

```
import re
string = "a. this is a sentence.bla bla."
string = re.sub(r"\A[a-h][.]","##", string)
```

The result is (obviously) "## this is a sentence.bla bla.".

How do I add to the string instead of replacing?

The result should be:
"##a. this is a sentence.bla bla."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
s = "a. this is a sentence.bla bla."
s = re.sub(r"\A[a-h][.]",r"##\g<0>", s)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##HcrBCoMwDIDhu08R4kXBBWFXN9hzWA9VwlpwtSTxsKevRfi/25//Fo70LCX@8iEGwo3CC9ATWIgKNQ/KyThtTOvuoSK8J2HSc@0E3Wf2j7DMtOAg2LbuO41vHED7JktM1mlfygU).

`"##\g<0>` inserts `##` before text matched (expressed with `\g<0>`).